# iPay88 (Payment Gateway) integration with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, http, post, payment-gateway

I'm developing an ecommerce application in asp.net integrating payment gateway.

I passed the parameters to REQUEST URL using HTTP POST Method like below

It doesn't redirecting to the payment form of iPay88 without asking confirmation in iPay88 payment form it directs to Response URL.

[image]

Comment: It's currently hard to understand what you're asking. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first then read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page so that you can describe your problem more clearly. To allow others to help you, you'll need to share [a sample of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the attempts you've made so far to solve the problem, and any other details relevant to your problem (like the expected and actual output). Also, please include your code as text in your question so that others are able to copy it.

Comment: @werner Thanks for your kind information and sorry for not describing problem clearly.