# iPay88 (Payment Gateway) integration with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, http, payment-gateway

I'm developing an E-commerce application in ASP.NET, which is integrating a payment gateway.

I passed the parameters to a REQUEST URL using HTTP POST Method like below, but it doesn't redirect to the payment form of iPay88.

```
Protected Sub btnPaymemt_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPaymemt.Click

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxxxx/xxxx.aspx?")

    Dim strParam As String = ""
    strParam += "MerchantCode=MXXXX0&"
    strParam += "PaymentId=&"
    strParam += "RefNo=POS00123&"
    strParam += "Amount=5200&"
    strParam += "Currency=MYR&"
    strParam += "ProdDesc=Photo Print&"
    strParam += "UserName=XXXXXXX&"
    strParam += "UserEmail=XXXXXX&"
    strParam += "UserContact=XXXXXX&"
    strParam += "Remark=&"
    strParam += "Lang=UTF-8&"
    strParam += "SignatureType=SHA256&"
    strParam += "Signature=ccd199c8a06ff585f7c2541ba1d804d9467dabe8ec147aa2efb7acb077691641&"
    strParam += "ResponseURL=../Members/responseurl.aspx&"
    strParam += "BackendURL=../Members/backendurl.aspx"

    Dim data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strParam)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentLength = data.Length

    Using stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    End Using

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
    Dim strResponse = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()

End Sub
```

Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPay88 (Payment Gateway) integration with ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853056/ipay88-payment-gateway-integration-with-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

For Payment Transaction with ipay88 you need to register Test Account with ipay88 and provide them your Response and backend url and also it doesn't allow to test with localhost hope this will help you.